# Why does my mouseout fadeOut work, but then fade in again?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a div which has a nested element inside it that shows when hovering over the div. This works.

On mouseout, the nested element is supposed to hide, which it does, but then immediately fades in again as though I have just performed a hover over the initial div.

I've made [a jsfiddle replicating the issue over here](http://jsfiddle.net/jSStY/1/).

The html is:

```
<div class="add_bag_large_wrap">

<div class="add_bag_large_droid" style="margin: 90px auto;">
        I am a button.
    <div class="add_includes">
        <p>Show on hover, hide on mouseout</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

​

The JS:

```
 $('.add_bag_large_droid').live('hover',function(){

     $(this).children('.add_includes').fadeIn();         

 }).mouseout(function(){

     $('.add_includes').fadeOut();

 });
 ​
```

The CSS:

```
.add_bag_large_wrap {
position: relative;
width: 390px;
height: 96px;
margin: 36px auto;
}

.add_bag_large_droid {
background: #ccc;
width: 390px;
height: 96px;
cursor: pointer;
background-size: 390px 192px;
position: static;
}

.add_includes {
background: #000; padding: 18px; color: #fff; position: absolute; 
bottom: 110px; left: 50%; margin-left: -148px;
display: none;
text-align: left;
}

.add_includes p {
font-size: 11px; color: #fff; margin: 0;
}
```

​
What is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.add_bag_large_droid').hover(function(){

     $(this).children('.add_includes').fadeIn();         

 },function(){

     $('.add_includes').fadeOut();

 });
 ​
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your JS code too:

```
 $('.add_bag_large_droid').hover(function(){
     $(this).find('.add_includes').fadeIn();         
 }, function(){
     $(this).find('.add_includes').fadeOut();
 });
```

Using `live()`:

```
$('.add_bag_large_droid').live({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).find('.add_includes').fadeIn();  
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).find('.add_includes').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: But what about using `live`? It can be dynamically added element.

Comment: Yep, not it looks exactly like my answer :)

Comment: I would recommend against using `live`, as it attaches events to the `document`, which could raise issues with event bubbling, not to mention the events may be inadvertently unbound by other code.

Answer (score 0):

if your `.add_bag_large_droid` element doesn't exist when the DOM initially loads, you want to use `delegate` to delegate your event, not `live`:

```
$('.add_bag_large_wrap').delegate('add_bag_large_droid',{
    'mouseover': function(){
        $(this).children('.add_includes').fadeIn();         
    },
    'mouseout': function(){
        $('.add_includes').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

`$('.add_bag_large_wrap')` represents the nearest ancestor that is guaranteed to exist when the DOM loads. if it is another element, change the selector.

Comment: His fiddle shows what version of jQuery he is using - 1.6.4 - so he can't use `on`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
$('.add_bag_large_droid').mouseover(function(){

     $(this).children('.add_includes').fadeIn();         

 });

 $('.add_bag_large_droid').mouseout(function(){

     $('.add_includes').fadeOut();

 });
```

Comment: He wants to use live for delegation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add_bag_large_droid').hover(
    function() {
         $(this).children('.add_includes').fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
         $('.add_includes').fadeOut();
    }
);
```

This should work, you can bind both mouseenter and mouseleave events with hover(), the above is the same as below:

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

You could also use:

```
$(selector).mouseover(handlerIn).mouseout(handlerOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of jquery it should looks like:

```
$(".add_bag_large_droid").on({
  mouseenter: function(){
         $(this).children('.add_includes').fadeIn();  
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
         $(this).children('.add_includes').fadeOut();  
  }});
​
```

But you set jquery version 1.6.4: in this case script will be the same but use `live` instead of `on`.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/jSStY/4/